# Is it correct to say 0 is a pole of $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ when it is defined only for real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, singularity

I know that in the context of complex analysis poles have positive integer order. But when dealing with real functions is the usage of the term 'pole' correct? If yes can there be a pole of non-integer order? If no is there a similar term to describe the singularity of $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ defined over real numbers?

Comment: The proper technical term is '(vertical) asymptote', but 'pole' is likely to be understood as a synonym in this context.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you very much. How can the order be expressed? For example how to express $k$ in $x^{-k}$?